# How to allocate set of values for each user in the CSV config

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am just wondering is there any way in the JMeter CSV config file to allocate values for each user using sharing mode All Threads?

What I am trying to say is in Load runner script when can assign  xx values for each user by choosing below options in the test data file.
For ex:

```
No.of users assigned to the script is 3
Select  next row: Unique
Update value on : Each iteration
When out of values: Continue in a cyclic manner
Allocate a user values in the Controller: Allocate 1000 values for each Vuser
```

Note: TestData has 9000 rows values.

I want to do same in the JMeter.I am using Sharing mode as All Threads .

Please advise!
Thanks,
Raj

Comment: So what's not working for you with default "CSV Data Set Config"? Is your goal to make sure each thread uses 1000 sequential values, or make sure 3 threads are only using 3000 rows and not all 9000, or both? Because other than those 2 issues, I think "CSV Data Set Config" is working the same way pretty much

Comment: Hi Kirin, Each user 1000 unique values allocated to them only.What I am trying to say is one user  should not step into another user's data allocated.-Raj

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy.  Preload the data into queue.  You can use any of the public queue services from Amazon,  CloudAzure, IBM  Public Cloud, Rackspace, etc... or something internal like RabbitMQ.   At the beginning of your iteration use a GET to pop the next value off of the queue and then use that data for your iteration.   When no more data exists then self terminate.

This is, by the way, a tool agnostic approach